# ldloc or ldloca?

Tags: c#, .net

When does the compiler choose ldloc or ldloca? My guess is that it chooses ldloca for interfaces and valuetypes. But is that it? Does it choose it for other things too?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`ldloca`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.ldloca.aspx) loads the *address* of a variable onto the stack.

It's used to pass variables as `ref` and `out` parameters.

Comment: But it seems to always use ldloca when dealing with interfaces.

Comment: @High: Can you give an example? I don't see that.

Comment: Another example of ldloca `int x = 5; string s = x.ToString();` ToString is called against the **address** of x.

Comment: @swax: Or, more generally, any method on a value type.